# Bootstrap 3 form-outline like mdbbootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mdbootstrap

My site uses Bootstrap 3.3.6 and like to renew some features. Found a great input feature form from MDBBootstrap 5 and like to add it. But unfortunally this framework uses Bootstrap 5. And I do not intend to upgrade.
The input form are similar to bootstrap standards, but when focused the field, the label goes up on outline. This feature saves a lot space when you form are big.

Has anyone some code for this? I know it uses css ans js.

[image]

[image]